# Is it possible to get properties of properties by command-line in Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In my build.gradle, I have a property like this:

```
   sourceSets {
      mtp {
        resources {
          exclude '**/*.html'
        }
      }
    }
```

Is it possible to get the properties of mtp via command-line? I can get root project properties:

```
gradle properties
sourceSets: [source set 'main', source set 'mtp', source set 'test']
```

But when I try below, it fails:

```
gradle sourceSets:properties
Project 'sourceSets' not found in root project.
```

My solution is always creating a specific new task for that purpose:

```
task mtp {
    sourceSets.mtp.properties.each {println it}
}
```

However I demand an easier and practical solution. Any opinions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently a built-in feature for discovering nested properties from the command line. Better discoverability of the build language/model is a planned feature on the way to 3.0. Until then, the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html) is the best source of information to answer such questions.